# Beamer Class Logo in Header

Tags: presentations

I created a presentation using the beamer class with texmaker. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

Now I would like to include a jpg where the red circle is located, so basically inside a palette. Can anybody help me how to do that?

The code:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,labelsep=none]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle% 
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%

\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\definecolor{UniDunkel}{RGB}{73,142,137}
\definecolor{UniHell}{RGB}{142,184,182}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UniDunkel}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,
bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title 
alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title 
example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UniDunkel!115}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure, fg=UniHell,  bg=UniHell}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UniDunkel!115}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=Orange}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!0!red}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=white,bg=alerted text.fg!0!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=white,bg=example text.fg!0!white}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame1}
}

\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame2}
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the `textpos` package and add your logo to the frame title

```
\usepackage{textpos} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-1cm)
        \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{textblock*}}
```

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,labelsep=none]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle% 
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
    \oldmacro\hfill%

    \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\definecolor{UniDunkel}{RGB}{73,142,137}
\definecolor{UniHell}{RGB}{142,184,182}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UniDunkel}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,
    bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{parent=normal text,use=block title 
    alerted,bg=block title alerted.bg!10!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title 
    example,bg=block title example.bg!10!bg}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UniDunkel!115}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure, fg=UniHell,  bg=UniHell}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=UniDunkel!115}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=Orange}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!0!red}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted text,fg=white,bg=alerted text.fg!0!white}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=white,bg=example text.fg!0!white}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{textpos} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-1cm)
        \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{textblock*}}



\begin{document}

    \section{Section1}
    \subsection{Subsection1}
    \frame
    {
        \frametitle{Frame1}
    }

    \section{Section2}
    \subsection{Subsection2}
    \frame
    {
        \frametitle{Frame2}
    }


\end{document}
```