# How to alter a beamer template

Tags: beamer

I am using the "Conference presentation" Beamer-Template from [this link](https://de.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations). I want to change it slightly, however. Here is what I want to do:

1. On the title page, I want to insert a figure below the date. I have no clue as on how to do this.
2. I want to insert a logo. I know, in the comments, the author of the template mentions one way to do this (the pgfdeclareimage part). However, I want this logo to appear on the upper right corner of every slight. So, starting on the second slight, at the top, there is this blue bar. And I want the logo to appear at the upper right corner, inside this bar. Is this possible? Is it possible only for .png or also for .svg ?

As always, very gratefull for help!

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{textpos} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-1cm)
        \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{./figures/web_rgb_en}
\end{textblock*}}

\title[Final Presentation] {Title of my Presentation }
\author[Author 1, Author 2] {Author 1 \and Author 2}
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{./figures/inst_logo}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And I am trying to insert [this figure.](http://%5Ctitlegraphic%7B%5Cincludegraphics[width=2cm]%7B./figures/comNets_logo%7D)

And If I try and include the `\titlegraphic` command, TeXstudio does not compile, it says: "File ended while scanning use of \titlegraphic"

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in a single questions. Nevertheless, for your second question see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180628/36296. Using png/pdf etc is certainly easier, but you could use the `svg` package (needs shell escape and some external tools installed)

Comment: thx very much, samcarter! - If I use the code provided in your link, for some reason, the figure appears in the upper right corner, but it is not completely on the slide! I was playing around with the textblock size and the graphic width, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: allright, samcarter, I did. I included both questions in the MWE.

Comment: I updated my answer, however I had to replace the image because the link in your question is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Concerning your first question, you can use `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}`
- for the second question, you could use the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180628/36296

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{textpos} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.956\textwidth,-0.9cm)
        \includegraphics[height=0.8cm,width=0.8cm]{example-image}
\end{textblock*}}

\title[Final Presentation] {Title of my Presentation }
\author[Author 1, Author 2] {Author 1 \and Author 2}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, thx so much, samcarter! .. I know you don't want me to ask several questions here, so I will open another if you wat. But would you know a way to make this blue bar fade in color from left to right?

Comment: @user503842 Have a look at the `Warsaw` theme. If this does not help please ask a new question

Comment: @user503842 See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285046/changing-the-title-frame-color-to-a-gradient and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402113/multiple-horizontal-shadings-in-tree-outer-theme